# Where to find .dSYM file for app built with Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, twitter-fabric, dsym

I've built an iOS application with Xamarin and need the .dSYM to get a complete crash log. The official documentation says the file is suppose to be at ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/. However, I do not have a folder named mtbs in ~/Library/Caches/Xamarin/. Anyone seen this before and know where to find the .dSYM-file?

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/questions/symbolicate-ios-crash/

Answer (score 4):

Select *Release configuration* and *Device* as deployment target and build your application.

[image]

Then you´ll find it here: AppDir/bin/iPhone/Release/{YourAppName}.app.dSYM

Answer (score 0):

When building an iOS app with Visual Studio for Mac or Visual Studio 2017, the .dSYM file that's needed to symbolicate crash reports will be placed in the same directory hierarchy as your app's project file (.csproj). The exact location depends on your project's build settings:

If you have enabled device-specific builds, the the .dSYM can be found in the following directory:

**/bin///device-builds/-/**

For example:

**TestApp/bin/iPhone/Release/device-builds/iphone8.4-11.3.1/**

If you have not enabled device-specific builds, the .dSYM can be found in the following directory:

**/bin///**

For example:

**TestApp/bin/iPhone/Release/**

You can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/troubleshooting/questions/symbolicate-ios-crash)